# Vue instance render convention

Tags: vuejs2, vue-loader

In the Vue template examples, a common convention is to have a `main.js` file be the Vue instance, and then render an imported `App.vue` component.  Why do this?  I can think of two reasons, but I wonder if there is an "official" reason why.

1. The Vue instance and Vue component API are slightly different (eg. `data` format).  This approach would minimize the code written in the Vue instance.
2. If using `vue-loader`, you have the benefit of combining `<template />`, `<script />`, and `<style />` tags into the `App.vue` component (which would have been `main.js`).

Are there more reasons?

**Reference:**

[vuejs-templates/webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/src/main.js)

Comment: The benefits of using single file components are well summarised here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: You're basically citing a document that explains my #2 reason.  Is there any *other* reason?  Not that I need more reasons, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

## Every file should have separate responsibility

It's generally a good idea to split tasks that differ in nature - here we have two cases:

- declaring and exporting a component
- importing and rendering

As we can see, **these are disparate and therefore should not be done in one place**. You should also ask "why would I *not* do it" in parallel to "why should I do it"; It may seem that this convention is contrived (based solely on small example), but in projects with moderate to large codebases it aids maintainability.

So, is there any reason you would not do it, given the microscale time cost and breaking out of convention?

---

#### A note on pure modules

Analyzing the cases in terms of side effects, we have:

- declaring and exporting a component, which **does not affect other modules**
- rendering imported component and therefore **introducing side effects**

As we can see, the first module is *pure* and the second is not.
Keeping operations that **do** introduce side effects in one place is generally a good idea.